# Why does pycharm not see pyenv old environment packages?

Tags: python, pycharm

When I create a new project and set python interpreter from existing environment then pycharm can not see any packages already installed in this pyenv environment earlier. And pycharm prints an error when I try to install new package.

But if I open pycharm console and create a new environment "pyenv virtualenv my_env" then it's all ok with it.

Is it a bug or a feature? How to fix old environments?

PyCharm 2023.1.1

Ubuntu 20.04